# How to invoke MSBuild via command prompt?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, web, publish

I have a website (not a web application) and I want to publish it from the command prompt in the same directory every night.

I don't want to use build automation tools like TeamCity, TFS, or third-party tools like Nant - it should be done with `MSBuild`.  How can I do this?

**Update:** in the Publish window the only option that should be checked is `Use Fixed naming and single page assemblies`.

Comment: it should be something like : **msbuild Portal.sln** or **msbuild website**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From your comment, your web project is a web site project and not a web application project.

In this case, 'Publish' target can not be the option but 'AspNetCompiler' is the solution.

Create an xml file with below content and call it from MSBuild.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="PrecompileWeb">
        <AspNetCompiler
            VirtualPath="/MyWebSite"
            PhysicalPath="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebSite\"
            TargetPath="c:\precompiledweb\MyWebSite\"
            Force="true"
            Debug="true"
            FixedNames="True"
        />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Reference to this task is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164291.aspx) and you can configure all your un/check options.

FixedName="True" equals the checking of 'use fixed naming and single page...' option.

Then you call this file from MSBuild instead of the solution file.

```
MSBuild your.xml /p:Configuration=<Debug/Release>
```

As long as your class libraries are referenced by your web site project, they'll be built together.

Comment: My Solution contains 4 `class projects` and one website, I want to build the project first and then Publish the website. can you please write a psudo code for this senario? the only setting for publish is **Use Fixed naming and single page assemblies** and other checkboxes shouldn't be checked. Thank you in advance

Comment: Your answer is exatly what I'm looking for, but unfortunately when I run your command (**MSBuild command**) I face with an error, **`This Application is already Precompiled`**. what is it for.

Comment: my problem resolved by removing PrecomciledWeb.Config from the path.

Answer (score 6):

```
MSBuild.exe **MYPROJ**.sln 
/p:outdir="Z:\output\\",OutputPath="Z:\output\\",webprojectoutputdir="Z:\output\\",configuration=RELEASE 
/t:Clean;Build 

/flp1:logfile=Z:\output\\\Log_msbuild.log;verbosity=detailed 
/flp2:logfile=Z:\output\\\Log_warnings.log;warningsonly;verbosity=detailed 
/flp3:logfile=Z:\output\\\Log_errors.log;errorsonly;verbosity=detailed 

/nologo 
/noconlog
```

İt can compile all Types of projects(Web,webservice,desktop,..) and it can create log files as(buildlog,error and warnings).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply, and thanks for the input alan. Unfortunately your suggestion did not work so I ended up doing the following:

- Choose `This build does not copy output files to a drop folder` under the Build defaults tab
- Use the default template under the Process tab
- Choose `AsConfigured` as the value for the `Output location` under `2. Build` under the Process tab
- Use this MSBuild argument string:

  `/p:DeployOnBuild=True;DeployTarget=PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder;PackageTempRootDir="\\192.168.x.x\Nightly\MainBranch";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false`

This result is the following folder which I use as the webroot for the test site: `\\192.168.x.x\Nightly\MainBranch\PackageTmp`.
This obviously isn't optimal since I would prefer not to have the `PackageTmp` folder and I also haven't tested what happens when there are multiple web applications in the same solution, but I can't use more time on this issue.

I really don't understand why Microsoft have made such a simple task so complicated.