# How to compile and run a finished C# project outside Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, compilation

My question requires a different answer than what was provided here: [How to compile the finished C# project and then run outside Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057878/how-to-compile-the-finished-c-sharp-project-and-run-it-outside-visual-studio)

I need to deliver my code to another student, have that student "make" or compile the code, and then have them run the executable from command line in Windows passing a command line argument.

The project was developed as a console application in Visual Studio 2013. Is there anything I can do in VS or are there steps I can take?

Comment: I have multiple files not just 1, it's 9.

Comment: [Single file compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712125/how-to-compile-and-run-a-single-class-file-cs-file). [Project compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858171/how-to-compile-a-c-sharp-project-from-source). [Using MsBuild](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854905/how-to-use-msbuild-with-command-prompt?lq=1). One of these help?

Comment: The [project compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858171/how-to-compile-a-c-sharp-project-from-source) is the most useful thank you! I'm going to read up to make sure I can pass a command line argument via msbuild